# Understanding PrevState in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and this might be a silly doubt. But I wasn't able to find the answer for this.
When using state in React, to keep the display updated we use PrevState.
For example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
setState(prevState => prevState +1);
```

I understand that prevState updates the state by 1 and keeps the UI up to date with the state value.

However, how is prevState assigned the value of the previous state. Isn't it just the name of the parameter of the arrow function? So how is this name assumed to be the previous state value?
In forEach loop the parameter represents an element of the list. But here, how is the parameter PrevState being assigned the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, React keeps an array of all states for a given instance of a component. For example, if you have

```
const comp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const clickHandler = () => setState(prevState => prevState +1);
  return <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
};
```

Then, because there's only one state for the component, on mount, React will have an array of one item that it stores internally:

```
[0]
```

When `useState` is called, the value that React currently has in its internal array for that state gets returned. So, with the above example, when you click, the state setter will tell React to update its internal state to:

```
[1]
```

After which the component re-renders due to the state change, so the state value returned by `useState` that re-render is 1.

When you use the callback form of the state setter, eg

```
setState(prevState => prevState +1);
```

The callback's parameter comes directly from React's internals. This can sometimes be more reliable than relying on the value in the outer state identifier, because the outer state value will be out of date if you previously set the same state without waiting for a re-render - for example, notice how the below increments the state by only 1 each click, rather than by 2.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    const clickHandler = () => {
      setCount(count + 1);
      setCount(count + 1);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        {count}
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

In contrast, if you use the callback version, as soon as you call the first state setter, React's internals for the state will be updated - and then the second time you call the state setter, the parameter passed will be the newly updated value React has in state for it:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    const clickHandler = () => {
      setCount(count => count + 1);
      setCount(count => count + 1);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        {count}
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

The callback approach is only needed if you have the possibility of a stale closure. If the value in state has no chance of being stale, then there's no need for the callback, and simply doing

```
setCount(count + 1);
```

will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

> how is prevState assigned the value of the previous state. Isn't it just the name of the parameter of the arrow function? So how is this name assumed to be the previous state value?

`prevState` is as you say just the name of the parameter of the function. There is nothing else we gain from the name `prevState`, apart from an understanding that `prevState` will be the *old* value of the state after that part of your component state is finally updated, this is why it is referred to as the *previous* state.

IMO, it is better terminology to use `oldState` rather than `prevState` when referring to state within the callback, but in reality, `oldState === state`.

#### Proving that `oldState` === `state` within `setState`

Remember that you can call `setState` with just a new value for the state instead of a callback. So the following will be equivalent to what you currently have:

```
setState(state + 1);
```

If we are to assume that the above use of `setState` is the correct way to add `1` to the current state (and yes it is correct), then we are safe to assume that in the use of `setState` like this:

```
setState(oldState => oldState +1);
```

`oldState` and `state` have to be the same.

Since we cannot use the name `state` within the `setState` callback, we can create an alias called `currentState` and we now have:

```
setState(currentState => currentState +1);
```

Therefore, `oldState` === `state`,

QED.

Comment: Ok after reading the above answers I have got some better insights. I was able to realize the below point after reading the answers:

Comment: As any parameter name would work, is it safe to assume that the parameters being passed(prevState/oldState) are being equated to state value inside the setState function and then the written code is executed. So for any parameter the parameter will be equated to the state value first which then makes sense as of how the parameter gets the value and after that the action on the parameter (which is equal to value) is taken and returned.

Comment: @Leo exactly. However, the value returned by the callback is not immediately applied to the state of the component i.e. you will not be able to see the result of changing your state, until after your component is re-rendered. For example, if you do `setState(oldState => oldState + 1); setState(oldState => oldState + 1)`, in both cases, `oldState` will have the same value. In like manner, if you do `setState(state + 1); setState(state + 1)`, then in each case `state` will be the same value it was before the first `setState` was called. The updated state applys after your component re-renders.